# i upload image then this error was show error:URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads on this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms

Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads.
onChange Profile-edit.js:27
React 23
js index.js:6
factory react refresh:6
Webpack 3

```
 <div className='border- border-black'
                        onClick={() => document.querySelector(".input-img").click()}>
                        <input type="file" accept='image/*' className='input-img' hidden 
                        onChange={({ target: files }) => {
                            files[0] && setFileName(files[0].name)
                            if (files) {
                                setImage(URL.createObjectURL(files[0]))
                            }
                        }} />
                        {image ? <img src={image} height={60} width={60} alt={fileName} /> :
                            <><MdCloudUpload color='#1475cf' size={60} /><p>Upload Photo</p></>}
                    </div>
```